# Question about prime numbers - How many prime factors greater than $m$ can the number $m^2+1$ have?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is my investigation:

For $m \leq 40$, all answers are $1$ except $7, 18, 21, 38$ (which is $0$). I would like to seek for hints for this question.

Comment: There can be at most one prime factor larger than $m$ since $(m+1)^2=m^2+2m+1>m^2+1$. This prime factor must morever have multiplicity $1$.

Comment: See also IMO 2008, P3.

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: You could write $m^2+1=(m+i)(m-i)$ and then try to apply any results about the primes of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ or any results of algebraic numbertheory of this type.

Comment: We won't be able to classify the "m's" for which there is no prime factor with the desired property.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $m^2+1$ has at least two prime factors greater than $m$. Call these $p$ and $q$, so $p\ge m+1$ and $q\ge m+1$. Then
$$
pq\ge (m+1)^2 = m^2+2m+1 > m^2+1.
$$
So $pq$ is strictly larger than $m^2+1$, but also divides $m^2+1$. This is a contradiction. We conclude that at most one such prime factor can occur.

As you have already observed, it is indeed possible for $m^2+1$ to have one prime factor larger than $m$. For example, when $m=2$, we have the prime factor $5>2$. It is also possible $m^2+1$ has no prime factors greater than $m$. For example, when $m=7$, we find that the only prime factors of $7^2+1=50$ are $2$ and $5$.

Comment: Your example of $m=1$ doesn't seem quite right, or am I missing something?

Comment: @user1729 If $m=1$, then $m^2+1=2$, not $3$. (but $2$ is the prime and $2>1$ so I think that your proof is still correct except $2$.

Comment: @ChrisLeary Yeah, that was a stupid mistake on my part. I corrected it.

Comment: @Kelvin Whoops - I've deleted my comment to save myself from further embarrassment!

Comment: @Mastrem - Let's just say careless error, they happen. I wish I had a dollar for every one I've made over the years (some on this site even). Keep on keepin' on. CL

Comment: @Mastrem I thought that my delivery is not effective. I mean that your proof holds for $m=1$.

Comment: @KelvinChan I know it also holds for $m=1$. But I was editing to correct anyway, and $m=2$ seemed nicer to me, somehow.